# Looking for Java's ThreadPool with the ability to fallback to serial execution

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I'm looking for a threadpool implementation that will not wait when no threads are immediately available in the pool and instead either resort to a serial execution or somehow else let caller know that some tasks that are scheduled for executions would have to wait until thread pool gets back threads that are currently busy.

The net effect I'm trying to achieve is to have parallel executions when possible and when thread pool is fully saturated execute remaining tasks serially in the current thread - that is, where scheduling attempt has been made - without waiting until threadpool gets back another thread.

While this seems doable, I still feel that doing it right would be a significant amount of work - perhaps mostly testing-wise, making sure that all corner cases are properly addressed, etc).

I'd like to avoid reinventing the wheel if this support is readily available in one form or the other in one of the JDK's threading-related library classes.

If some other widely known libraries like Guava or Apache Commons offer that functionality I'd be curious knowing that too.

Comment: Why would you want to explicitly block the main thread? It's not like stuff will get done any faster, you'll just have a less responsive system.

Comment: A bit of context to clarify: at the moment system is executing tasks serially, so even if all the tasks are scheduled serially (or thread pool size is zero) I expect to see only a minimal performance regression related to thread pool query overhead. With the thread pool I'm looking for I expect to see the end result to NEVER have worse performance than what I have now.

Comment: How are the tasks coming in though? You'll need to parallelize the accepting code so it can accept several tasks as well. Best provide some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with the [standard ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html):

- To stop tasks from queueing when no threads are available, use `SynchronousQueue` as the queue implementation.
- To have the caller run the submitted task when no thread is available in the pool, use `ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy` as the task rejection policy.

These two parameters can be set by calling the constructor:

```
ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, timeUnit,
    new SynchronousQueue<>(), new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy())
```